# Why is my IDEA gradle.build script not importing Guava?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have never really done build automation before, but I'm trying to learn how to use Gradle. I never was interested in build automation but I'm finding it increasingly necessary nowadays.

I'm trying to create a new IDEA project. It has some dependencies on Guava immutable collections. I implemented the following gradle.build script.

[image]

But no matter how I try to run the build, or clean/rebuild the project... the Guava library never seems to be included in the project and the compile errors remain.

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong? What tasks am I missing to get this to compile with all the dependencies?

Comment: Did you add the `build.gradle` via the `gradle` tool window? Open the project configuration dialog and see if there are any `problems`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Gradle tool window and click refresh button.

[image]